# How to close MongoDB connection in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Consider a python script like below which has many if else conditions and many try except blocks. I want to close the MongoDB connection after the MongoDB operations. Is the below mentioned way a proper way to close the connection?

```
def temp_fun():
    try:
        client = MongoClient(DB_NAME)  # from PyMongo
        if some_condition:
            # code 
            if client:
                client.close()
            return True
        elif some_condition:
            # code
            if client:
                client.close()
            return True
        else some_condition:
            # code
            if client:
                client.close()
            return True
    except:
        if client:
            client.close()
        return None
```

Comment: Perhaps set a variable with the return value in each if/elseif/else clause, close `client`, and then return?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close pymongo connections, python and pymongo handles all the clean-up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [finally](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-except-else-and-finally-in-python/), as it's always executed regardless of the possible exceptions generated in code.

Comment: my function has a return in each of the if conditions. How would using "finally" help me?